# Unity3d ProBuilder Spheres causing high lag?

Tags: unity-game-engine, modeling, lag

Hello im modeling a CCTV Camera in Unity3d using ProBuilder. Now in this picture you can see I'm using spheres to create these kind of red lights within the camera
[image: VIEW HERE]

Now when I spawn in the game using an FPSController and run against the camera my statistics look like this.

[image: STATISTICS]

I have 2 fps and high ms.

When running normally around the map my statistics are fine
[image: NORMAL STATISTICS]

I tried to make the red spheres static but that did not fix my problem. I don't really know what the cause of this issue is so I don't really know what I can try to fix this.

Comment: Are you sure its the spheres and not the raytraced(?) reflection in the middle?

Comment: the reflection in the middle is fine, I deleted it and tried again but it did not fix the issue

Comment: have you tried runninng the profiler to check where is the resource consumption going?

Comment: Yes this is what happens when I run into the camera. https://i.imgur.com/tpCYRR8.png. Even tho I have no animations

Comment: This sounds to me like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why are you modelling something like a CCTV camera with ProBuilder in the first place? ProBuilder is designed to build world geometry, not to model objects.

Comment: yeah modeling with ProBuilder is a bad idea. I made the same camera in blender and now everything works fine. No clue why it lagged before tho